# Firebase Storage Completion Handler not called

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, completionhandler

I use Firebase Storage to store images. Everything uploads as expected and the images appear on the Firebase console but for whatever reason the completion handler doesn't fire so the progress HUD doesn't disappear. I've set a break-point at line 6 so that's how I know that the completion handler doesn't fire. Can someone explain to me why this could happen?

```
guard let imageData = imageToUpload.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else { return }
let task = spaceRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }
    self.dismissProgressHUD()
})
task.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
    guard let progress = snapshot.progress else { return }
    print(progress)
})
task.observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
    print("succes")
    self.dismissProgressHUD()
})
```

dismissProgressHUD() is a method inside an extension of UIViewController.

```
func dismissProgressHUD() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
<NSProgress: 0x281d88140> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 2095130  
<NSProgress: 0x281d88140> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0001 / Completed: 115 of 2095245  
<NSProgress: 0x281d8b520> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0040 / Completed: 8307 of 2095245  
<NSProgress: 0x281d8b480> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 2095245 of 2095245  
2019-02-22 08:21:42.665537+0100 Binfinder[320:23087] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C11.1:2][0x1407a9660] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-02-22 08:21:42.665806+0100 Binfinder[320:23087] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C11.1:2][0x1407a9660] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-02-22 08:21:42.666331+0100 Binfinder[320:23087] TIC Read Status [11:0x0]: 1:57
2019-02-22 08:21:42.666368+0100 Binfinder[320:23087] TIC Read Status [11:0x0]: 1:57
```

Comment: if you implement task.observe(.success) does it get called? Documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files

Comment: task.observe(.success) doesn't get called as well. I've updated this post with the console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the CocoaPods to the latest versions and now everything is working as it should.